# Pulling data from csv file for specific columns that user inputs (no pandas)

Tags: python, csv, file, for-loop, user-input

I need help with a code that takes a user's input of specific columns they want from a large csv file I have. After they type in themselves a column they want, they also must type an integer input. That integer input will give them that number of results of the lowest occurrences for that column. For example if they type: hospital_name, "5", it will show them 5 different hospitals(there are at least 50 different hospital names under that column) that have the lowest count tied with them. I will write an example input and output:

Type in which column you want:  hospital_name
Type in how many lowest results you want:  3

An output may look like:

```
                      400 births are tied to Gains Hospital                                                                            
                      347 births are tied to Petri Hospital 
                      200 births are tied to Brit Hospital
```

The whole csv is a report on births, so you have to count how many times an item is in each column and report that (most low counts)

I already read my csv file by using "with"

I am having trouble making the loop to connect all of this. 
I know user input itself will be input() and int(input()), but that does not connect me back to csv file.

Comment: How does the software know you want to show births as and hospital names.  Meaning you entered column_name as hospital. How does it know you want to see births for the different hospitals rather than some other column in the CSV file?

Comment: The whole csv is a report on births, so you have to use COUNT i'm pretty sure. You have to count how many times an item is in each column, does that make sense?

Comment: @webbpie--Does a row show all births for a hospital, or can births at a hospital be in multiple rows which would necessitate summing for a hospital?  Meaning would one row be `400,Gains` or would you have Gains hospital mentioned several times and you would have to add the rows with Gains to get to 400?

Comment: Great question, I should have clarified that, sorry! It's the last thing you said, so you would count how many times Gains appears throughout that column and report that number. If the user wants 3 results, it should output the 3 lowest counts for items in the column they specified.

Comment: @webbpie--okay, take a look at the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

```
import csv

column_name = input('Which column: ').upper()
number_lowest = int(input('How many lowest: '))

# Calculate births by specified column name
with open("data.csv", "r") as f:
  reader = csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=",")
  births_count = {}
  for d in reader:
    # Use column_name as key
    # accumulate births for this key
    if not d[column_name] in births_count:
      births_count[d[column_name]] = 0
    births_count[d[column_name]] += 1 # since each row is a different birth

# Find number_lowest lowest births
lowest_births = {}
for i in range(number_lowest):
  # By looping number_lowest times, 
  # we find this many lowest values
  if len(births_count) > 0:
    # find lowest births
    lowest_val = 1e37 # just use a large number
                      # that we know actual
                      # count will be less than

    lowest_name = ""
    for name, value in births_count.items():
      if value < lowest_val:
        lowest_val = value
        lowest_name = name

    # Add to lowest births
    lowest_births[lowest_name] = lowest_val

    # remove from births_count
    # this reduces count of items in dictionary
    del births_count[lowest_name]
  else:
    break  # births_count is empty

# Output results
for name, births in lowest_births.items():
  print(f"{births} births are tied to {name} {column_name.title()}")
```

**Test**

Made up comma-delimited CSV data with three columns: births,hospital,location

```
File: data.csv

HOSPITAL_NAME,BIRTH_DAY, BIRTH_YEAR, BIRTH_WEIGHT
Gains,1/14,2015,8.5 lbs
Mayo Clinic,2/11,2018,6.5 lbs
Gains,1/15,2016,8.9 lbs
Stanford Health Care,2/15,2016,7.4 lbs
Mayo Clinic,11/10,2018,7.3 lbs
Gains,1/09,2011,7.5 lbs
John Hopkins,12/23,2012,6.9 lbs
Massachusetts General,9/14,2001,8.3 lbs
Stanford Health Care,8/17,2005,7.6 lbs
Massachusetts General,7/18,2016,8.7 lbs
John Hopkins,3/11,2017,7.2 lbs
Massachusetts General,4/16,2014,7.4 lbs
Northwestern Memorial,10/12,2012,8.3 lbs
UCLA Medical Center,9/19,2011,8.1 lbs
Petri,11/21,2003,7.5 lbs
UCSF Medical Center,2/15,2004,7.9 lbs
```

Example Run:

```
Which column: hospital_name
How many lowest: 5
HOSPITAL_NAME
1 births are tied to Northwestern Memorial Hospital_Name
1 births are tied to UCLA Medical Center Hospital_Name
1 births are tied to Petri Hospital_Name
1 births are tied to UCSF Medical Center Hospital_Name
2 births are tied to Mayo Clinic Hospital_Name
```

**Update Find Max Using Insertion Sort**

```
import csv

# Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-insertion-sort/
def insertionSort(arr): 
  " Inplace location sort "
  # Traverse through 1 to len(arr) 
  for i in range(1, len(arr)): 
    key = arr[i] 
    # Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are 
    # greater than key, to one position ahead 
    # of their current position 
    j = i-1
    while j >=0 and key < arr[j] : 
            arr[j+1] = arr[j] 
            j -= 1
    arr[j+1] = key

def find_maxs_by_sort(data, number):
  """ Finds extreems of mins or max's 
      depending upn bLowest flag
  """

  # Get list of key, value pairs as tuples of (value, key)
  tuple_list = []
  for k, v in data.items():
    tuple_list.append((v, k))

  # Sort will be in ascending order
  # Does an inplace sort
  # insertSort also works on array of tuples
  # Will sort by v since it's first in the each tuple
  insertionSort(tuple_list)

  # Place sorted tuples back as a dictionary
  # tuples are sorted by [(v1, k1), (v2, k2), ...]
  # We start at the end and work backwards since sort is
  # in ascending order
  n = len(tuple_list)
  results = {}
  for i in range(n-1, n - number - 1, -1):
    v, k = tuple_list[i]
    results[k] = v

  return results

for i in range(3):
  # To do this 3 times
  column_name = input('Which column: ').upper()
  number = int(input('How many maxs: '))

  with open("data.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=",")
    births_count = {}
    for d in reader:
      # Use column_name as key
      # accumulate births for this key
      if not d[column_name] in births_count:
        births_count[d[column_name]] = 0
      births_count[d[column_name]] += 1 # since each row is a different birth

  # find max
  max_births = find_maxs_by_sort(births_count, number)

  # Output results
  for name, births in max_births.items():
    print(f"\t{births} births are tied to {name} {column_name.title()}")
```

Comment: results[d[column_name]] += int(d['births']) , it is showing that 'births' is a key error.

Comment: @webbpie--here's [online running code](https://repl.it/@DarrylGurganiou/csvSpecificColumns).  You can run it by hitting green run button at top.

Comment: @webbpie--are you saying this is a CSV file without a header row.  Just to make sure: What is the file delimiter?  Seems three inputs are needed: 1) column number of the hospitals, 2) column number for births, 3) how many lowest rows do you want.  Does this seem correct?

Comment: There are 14 different column headers. They all have headers in excel. for example, one is CITY_BIRTH. Also, how would I do this without setdefault()? We never learned that, so we cannot use it. sorry for the confusion. Your help has been great so far.

Comment: @webbpie--sure setdefault there are alternatives to setdefault.  Can you provide a link to the data or a sample of some of the data?

Comment: CITY_BIRTH, BIRTH_DAY, BIRTH_YEAR, BIRTH_WEIGHT

Comment: @webbpie--so is each row information on a different birth (BIRTH_DAY, BIRTH_YEAR, BIRTH_WEIGHT)?  Does the hospital column have a name?

Comment: the hospital column is the first column header, and its called HOSPITAL_NAME. I forgot to mention, all of the headers are capitalized. There is various data in each row, yes

Comment: @webbpie--take a look at the update.  You can also look at the [link](https://repl.it/@DarrylGurganiou/csvSpecificColumns)

Comment: That looks great! thank you so much. one last question, what is another way I can write 
sorted_results = sorted(results.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])? We did not learn lambda. We did learn items(), so I can keep that.

Comment: @webbpie--okay, updated a version that doesn't use sort or lambdas.  Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: @webbpie--don't fret about asking questions since I learn also.  For instance, I'm so used to finding mins by sorting with lambda I had to think for a minute for another option.  Anyway to find max, you set the initialize `max_val = 0`, and you update max_val to current value, if the current value is greater (pattern for finding min and max using a for loop).

Comment: @webbpie--are you familiar with functions yet?  If so, I could show you a solution based upon functions.

Comment: @webbpie--though the code is 90% the same it's better if finding min or max was a different function.

Comment: @webbpie--you're off to a good start.  1) Since you're finding max, I would use max_val and max_births rather than lowest_val and lowest_births.  One issue is that when I found the lowest I deleted values from births_count which will make finding the maximums afterwards no longer work.  So, you have to make a copy of births_count before calculating the mins or max's.

Comment: @webbpie-take a look at [link](https://repl.it/@DarrylGurganiou/csvSpecificColumns).  It does 3 mins followed by 3 maxs.  Python may be difficult now, but it gets easier, much easier.

Comment: @webbpie--it's outputting ones since the four lowest births is 1.  You have to ask for 5 mins to get your first 2 in the result.  The results should be more interesting for a more realistic dataset.  You can remove the min code--lines 48 to 63--for min results and the max code should still work.

Comment: @webbpie--do you mean this [with just maxs](https://repl.it/@DarrylGurganiou/csvSpecificColumns)?

Comment: @webbpie--no worries on questions.  I'm working on other things in parallel so not a problem. Anyway, this method is similar to scoring board.  1st place goes to the highest scorer which you find by the max over all the players.  To find the 2nd place, you remove the top, scorer then find the max again.  Similar for 3rd , 4th, etc.  Does that answer your question?  You would normally just use the sort function but when you're sorting a dictionary.items(), each value is a tuple so you need a key function.  That's where the lambda came in.

Comment: @webbpie--suppose you had the numbers [3, 2, 4].  How would you do that.  1) You go over the list and pick the largest, which is 4.  Remove 4 from the list, so now you have [3, 2].  2) Go over new list and pick largest, the answer is 2.  Remove 2 from the list.  So you have the largest two values being 4 and 2.  That's what  find_maxs is doing.  It's not sorting.  I'lll make another function that uses sorting without lambda.

Comment: @webbpie--made [another version](https://repl.it/@DarrylGurganiou/csvSpecificColumns) that uses sort.

Comment: @webbpie--count is based upon there being one birth per row.  When increment the bin corresponding to the value in the column we're monitoring.  So if we're doing the HOSPITAL_NAME column, and the value in that column is "John Hopkins" we increment `births_count["John Hopkins"]`.  The value is from `d[column_name]` which is updated for each row as I loop using `for d in reader`.  Are you familiar with using csv.DictReader for reading CSV files?

Comment: @webbpie--it's Python's built-in sort which I believe is [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).

Comment: @webbpie--by the way, with Python any built-in library function is normally much faster than something you could code yourself in pure Python.  The reason is built-in functions are normally coded in C/C++.

Comment: @webbpie-the code I previously had did not use sort.  It just uses the method you would use if you looked at Olympic times for a 100 m race and I asked you who came in first.  You would go down the list of times and pick the runner with the shortest time.  For 2nd, you would go over the list (ignoring the shortest time) and again pick the runner with the shortest time.  In this method, you are not sorting the list.

Comment: @webbpie--the one with sorting would look similar except we would have to find and then include a selection or insertion sort function.  Did the instructor ask you to a selection or insertion sort rather than the built-in sort function?

Comment: @webbpie--has the system (Stackoverflow) prompted you about moving the discussion to private chat?  Surprisingly it hasn't for me and it normally does after just a few back and forth with other users.

Comment: I know! I prefer to chat at this point rather than commenting. it says you do not have enough points to chat

Comment: @webbpie--upvoting your question gave you 10.  You just need 9 more points to chat.  Here's an example of [insertion sort in Python](https://stackabuse.com/insertion-sort-in-python/).  Can you tell if this code is okay for you to use?

Comment: @webbpie--updated [link](https://repl.it/@DarrylGurganiou/csvSpecificColumns) to perform insertion sort.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thank you SO much for your help. You explained things so clearly and I know that I learned a lot today. You're the best.

Comment: Hello DarrylG, I meant to respond to you earlier but I have been working on other things. How can I upvote you if my reputation is not high enough? I cannot thank you enough for your previous help. I have some new questions about a different topic I am learning now, and I thought maybe you could help me? I do not know how to chat though.

Comment: @webbpie--no worries.  Although you may not have reputation to upvote an answer, I think you can accept an answer.  I think we can't chat until your reputation reaches 20 so not sure how to see your questions unless you post them.

Comment: I just accepted your answer. I will upvote it once I reach 15 reputation points.

Comment: I will comment here once I post my new question because I wanted only your help because you explain things thoroughly. Are you good with Python classes, methods, and attributes?

Comment: @webbpie--don't worry about that.  Is there any suggestions on how I could see your question and provide feedback?   Can you post your new question on Stackoverflow or is it not formulized enough for that?

Comment: @webbpie--I'm I good with Python classes methods and attributes?  Tough to say.  I would hate to say yes, then get stumped by your first question.  Also, great if others also can answer since you may find them to be even a better source of knowledge.

Comment: I have not posted it yet. When I do, I will comment here, and you should be able to go to my profile and view the question. If I go to your profile now, I can see questions you answer and ask.

Comment: I just posted the question. Let me know if you can view it :)

Comment: @webbpie--I can see the question.  I would suggest you temporarily delete it until you can add more information (i.e. some code) to it.

Comment: I just edited it to add some code of what I have so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216134/discussion-between-darrylg-and-webbpie).

Comment: Hey look at the chat here instead. It is right above this comment.